# What is the problem in code syntax in jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

library(dslabs)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data(reported_heights)

```
    dat <- mutate(reported_heights, date_time = ymd_hms(time_stamp)) %>%
      filter(date_time >= make_date(2016, 01, 25) & date_time < make_date(2016, 02, 1)) %>%
      mutate(type = ifelse(day(date_time) == 25 & hour(date_time) == 8 & between(minute(date_time), 15, 30), "inclass","online")) %>%
      select(sex, type)
    
    y <- factor(dat$sex, c("Female", "Male"))
    x <- dat$type
    
      Error in library(dslabs): there is no package called 'dslabs'
Traceback:

  
 2. library(dslabs)
```

Comment: In spite of all the down votes I think this is a legitimate issue that someone beginning data analysis might have

Comment: Your tags should identify the language that the code is written in.  It clearly isn't `python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter can be used with an R kernel (which is what your code is written in), but the default is Python. If you have an R kernel installed then you should be able to select it from the dropdown menu in the top right.

If you don't have the option to use R then you'll need to install the kernel. This is quite straightforward if you are using conda, just run `conda install -c r r-irkernel` from the command line.

You will presumably need to restart Jupyter after successfully installing the necessary R kernel. You should then be able to run R code in your Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please tick to accept the answer if that was helpful :)

Comment: @Vira I know it isn't always obvious to new users, but "accept" is the checkmark. You can even accept *and* upvote (the up arrow). Welcome to StackOverflow!